# Linux C Compiler

Tags: linux, path, yum, c

I've just tried to install APCUPSD and have run into a missing C compiler error. I then ran

```
yum install compat-gcc-34-g77
```

which went fine but the error did not go away, I tried

```
which gcc
```

as well as

```
which compact-gcc
```

both returned the errors

```
/usr/bin/which: no gcc in
(/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/trent/bin)
```

how do I make sure it is in the $PATH?

UPDATE

I should probably mention the path to where the gcc is

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the path `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/` to your `$PATH` environment variable.

Put in a line in `~/.profile` as follows:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
```

It will add the path to the variable. But in the current session, the file must be sourced again to be applied. Use that command for that:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Then `which gcc` should reply the correct path.

Comment: Adding the location to the PATH isn't the problem it's just that even when I add it it doesn't find the gcc, I'm not sure how to check where the right location is to add

Comment: When which doesn't find it, then its not in the PATH. Make sure the directory containing the executable gcc is in the $PATH (not a parent or something, **exactly** that directory). You can check your PATH with `echo $PATH`. And also make sure it is executable. Try is with `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/gcc --version` Is there an output?

Comment: thats exactly where the problem lies, there is no executable gcc in that directory. when I use whereis gcc it gives me that location though

Comment: I found the problem, the gcc had been uninstalled incorrectly so it only looked like it was there, an incredibly frustrating situation

Comment: Im still going to mark that as the correct answer because you helped me to confirm that it was definitely not there, thanks bro