# What is the correct location of gcc is on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, cmake

I am trying to build the software package [Trilinos](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#simple-serial-instructions-enables-most-packages), and I think it failed because it couldn't locate the C compiler directory correctly. Can anyone tell what the correct location of `gcc` is on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer? I actually need the C, C++ and fortran directory locations.

I am using the build script:

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=<path to C compiler> \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<path to C++ compiler> \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=<path to Fortran compiler> \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_ALL_PACKAGES=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PATH=<path to install Trilinos into> \
<path to Trilinos source>

make -j<n> install
```

I used directories:

```
<path to C compiler> = /usr/bin
<path to C++ compiler> = /usr/bin
<path to Fortran compiler> = /usr/bin
```

I assume C is `gcc-5`, C++ is `g++-5` and fortran is `gfortran-5`?

Should the directory be `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu` from [Linux C Compiler](https://superuser.com/questions/871490/linux-c-compiler)?

The cmake build gave error message (end part of build output):

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path requires the full path including filename, using:

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: If you use bash (which you probably do), `type` is often better than `which`. `which` is an external command that does not have any knowledge of your shell environment, so cannot respond to e.g. shell builtins or functions, but `type` is a shell builtin so can. `type` is also more explicit when the given command isn't found; `which` prints nothing, but `type` responds with a "not found".